# ¿Cómo acceder a una variable local y una variable global con el mismo nombre?

Tags: c++, variables-globales

Teniendo el siguiente programa, ¿es posible acceder al valor de **`x`** global, es decir, el que se encuentra fuera del `main()` (en este caso 10)?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int x = 10;

int main() {
    int x = 2;
    cout << "\nlocal Variable x = " << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En C++, puedes usar el operador de resolución de ámbito:

```
int x = 10;

int main( ) {
    int x = 2;

    cout << "Variable global x= " << ::x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

En C, es algo más *rebuscado*:

```
int x = 10;

int main( void ) {
    int x = 2;

    {
        extern int x;

        printf( "%d\n", x );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Una condición **indispensable** en C es que dicha variable **no puede estar declarada como `static`**:

```
static int x = 10;

int main( void ) {
    int x = 2;

    {
        extern int x;

        printf( "%d\n", x );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> error: variable previously declared `static` redeclared `extern`

Comment: `::x ` es la variable global, no? Creo que lo has puesto al revés en el `cout`.

Comment: @EequiisVásquez La idea es que mostrara la global; mostrar la local no tiene ninguna complicación :-)

Comment: Correcto @EequiisVásquez, es la global. Con tu permiso, Trauma, he editado la respuesta con esa corrección.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Trauma no sabía del uso de ese operador. La pregunta era orientada a c++, pero puse también C, porque suelen ser muy parecido, en este caso también me ha sido muy interesante ver las diferencias que existen!